# Can iostat output show mismatched read data for mdadm raid5 array?

Tags: raid, mdadm, raid5, iostat

I'm trying to understand this `iostat` output:

```
      tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_dscd/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn    kB_dscd Device
   500.30        58.9M        19.4k         0.0k     329.1G     108.5M       0.0k sdc
   500.26        58.9M        19.5k         0.0k     329.1G     109.1M       0.0k sdd
   500.40        58.9M        19.3k         0.0k     329.1G     107.8M       0.0k sde
  3027.72         1.4G        15.3k         0.0k       7.9T      85.6M       0.0k md3
```

`md3` is a mdadm raid5 array with 3 disks, namely `sdc, sdd, sde`. After rebooting the systems I noticed that the `kB_read` for `md3` are way too high and also `kB_read/s` doesn't make much sense.

Can anyone explain what I'm seeing here? Thanks

Tried rebooting just to test if it was something transient, but I see the same behavior, here's another set of outputs:

```
$ iostat -h
      tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_dscd/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn    kB_dscd Device
     4.72       567.4k         1.3k         0.0k      13.7G      32.6M       0.0k sde
     4.71       567.1k         1.3k         0.0k      13.7G      32.6M       0.0k sdd
     4.74       568.0k         1.3k         0.0k      13.7G      32.7M       0.0k sdc
    26.95        14.3M         0.1k         0.0k     352.5G       3.6M       0.0k md3

$ iostat -x -k
Device            r/s     rkB/s   rrqm/s  %rrqm r_await rareq-sz     w/s     wkB/s   wrqm/s  %wrqm w_await wareq-sz     d/s     dkB/s   drqm/s  %drqm d_await dareq-sz  aqu-sz  %util
sde              4.62    567.55     4.39  48.73    6.80   122.84    0.10      1.31     0.16  62.47   31.47    13.56    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.03   0.41
sdd              4.61    567.26     4.39  48.77    7.40   123.03    0.10      1.32     0.16  62.23   30.94    13.45    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.04   0.41
sdc              4.64    568.11     4.39  48.62    9.21   122.46    0.10      1.32     0.16  62.54   34.15    13.58    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.05   0.45
md3             26.95  14609.87     0.00   0.00   11.97   542.02    0.00      0.15     0.00   0.00   57.84    36.75    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.32   0.36
```

The system is a Synology NAS:

```
Linux myhost 4.4.59+ #25426 SMP PREEMPT Mon Dec 14 18:48:50 CST 2020 x86_64 GNU/Linux synology_apollolake
mdadm - v3.4 - 28th January 2016
```

Added info of the array:

```
$ sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md3
/dev/md3:
        Version : 1.2
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 3
  Total Devices : 3
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent
          State : clean 
 Active Devices : 3
Working Devices : 3
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0
         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K
    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       35        0      active sync   /dev/sdc3
       1       8       51        1      active sync   /dev/sdd3
       2       8       67        2      active sync   /dev/sde3

$ cat /proc/mdstat 
md3 : active raid5 sdc3[0] sde3[2] sdd3[1]
      27335120896 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/3] [UUU]
```

Adding another test comparing `iostat` vs `/proc/diskstats`:

```
$ iostat -h | grep -E "sdc|sdd|sde|md3"
     0.42        41.7k        18.2k         0.0k      13.7G       6.0G       0.0k sde
     0.41        41.7k        18.2k         0.0k      13.7G       6.0G       0.0k sdd
     0.42        41.9k        18.2k         0.0k      13.8G       6.0G       0.0k sdc
     2.54         1.0M        35.6k         0.0k     352.5G      11.7G       0.0k md3

$ iostat | grep -E "sdc|sdd|sde|md3"
sde               0.42        41.74        18.15         0.00   14386484    6255981          0
sdd               0.41        41.69        18.15         0.00   14372460    6256545          0
sdc               0.42        41.85        18.15         0.00   14425589    6257257          0
md3               2.54      1072.39        35.55         0.00  369661368   12255776          0

$ cat /proc/diskstats | grep -E "sdc |sdd |sde |md3 " 
   8      64 sde 118510 112430 28772968 809485 24872 1535475 12512035 547302 0 288110 1356601
   8      48 sdd 117848 112258 28744920 875289 24860 1535638 12513163 538100 0 271284 1413110
   8      32 sdc 120234 112230 28851178 1103193 24846 1535822 12514587 746998 0 319872 1849980
   9       3 md3 683014 0 739322736 8168833 191860 0 24511552 14120302 0 131259 22257749
```

Comment: Can you show the output of `iostat -x -k` ?

Comment: I modified the question with that output too, thanks for helping @shodanshok

Comment: On which system (exact version) do you encounter this?

Comment: Thanks @NikitaKipriyanov Added more info above -- do you need other info?

Comment: I agree that the ratio between `md3` and the various component devices does not seem to make much sense. As it seems to be a Synology NAS, I would write on their forum to ask for clarifications.

Comment: Not only ratio, I don't believe 3 hard drives could give 1.4G/s of total read speed. It is worth compare `iostat -h` with just `iostat`. I start thinking there is a bug in iostat bundled with Synology DSM, i.e. `-h` conversion is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, will open a ticket.

Comment: by default, `iostat` [parses](https://github.com/sysstat/sysstat/blob/v12.5.2/common.h#L78) `/proc/diskstats` for disk statistics (format is space-separated [values](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/procfs-diskstats)), probably check if `/proc/diskstats` is populated correctly?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @mforsetti, I added to the question a comparison between `iostat` and `/proc/diskstats`. Doesn't make much sense either but I need to look at it carefully.

Comment: Can you compare the output of `dstat` too? Should be available with `ipkg`

Comment: Sorry, can't install new stuff on these prod systems.